# interpretation of 'I stayed some days' --- 'for some days straight' or 'on days for a total of some days'?

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

A stand-alone sentence, '**I stayed some days**' --- if 'some' in this sentence were restricted to meaning 'an unspecified number of,' which would it mean

1. I stayed **on** days for a total of an unspecified number of days, or
2. I stayed **for** an unspecified number of days straight

?

Comment: 1. The sentence, as written, looks ambiguous to me. 2. I'm having a hard time parsing "I stayed on days...." Did you mean "I stayed during the daytime for an unspecified number of days"?

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. I plain wanted to know whether the sentence means one or the other more likely. By 'days' I mean simple units on the calendar. Yes, right, it's vague. I'm a cognitive sematicist and I just wanted to know if either prevails in implicature by majority.

Comment: I guess I just don't understand what on + [unit of time] is supposed to mean. I don't think I've ever seen that construction before.

Comment: I stayed on Tuesday, Wednesday, and Thursday. I stayed on three days. By extension, I thought of 'on some days.' I'm a non-native speaker. I would appreciate your input, Kevin.

Comment: On + [determiner] + day(s) is fine (e.g. "some", "three", "any", "every", "the", etc.). But if you drop the determiner, I think it's ungrammatical.

Comment: 'For days' is okay, but 'on days' is not, then.

Comment: Just to boot, we grammarians tend to use a simple, ambiguous sentence, which could be polysemic. :-) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

In writing, *I stayed some days* is potentially ambiguous without context. In speech, if you meant *on some days and not others* you would put a stress on the word *some.*

*It rained some days* would probably be interpreted as *on some days* unless you included the word *for.*

Comment: Thanks, Kate. So you would perceive 'on' there. You don't feel the sentence is a product of for-deletion, then.